# Can indentation and wrapping of flow-style YAML output be specified using yaml-cpp?

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I'm using the `yaml-cpp` library to output YAML that contains some long-ish lists that I'd like to output in "flow" style, with the content split across multiple lines as needed. An example of what I'm aiming for is:

```
- data: [blah, blah, blah, blah,
         blah, blah, blah, blah,
         blah, blah]
```

I'm running into two stumbling blocks, though. First, if I insert `YAML::Newline` into the stream, then the next line is indented only to the level of the parent element, e.g.:

```
- data: [blah, blah, blah, blah,
  blah, blah, blah, blah,
  blah, blah]
```

which isn't terribly readable. I've tried inserting `YAML::Indent(N)` into the stream at various points, but none of the options seems to have any effect on the indentation of the lines in question.

Second, while I know the width of my list elements, I haven't found a way to know what the starting column for the list is, in order to wrap the output before hitting column 80, for example.

Any ideas on how to improve this formatting would be appreciated. The code I've written which generates the second set of output:

```cpp
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

YAML::Emitter& operator<<(YAML::Emitter& out,
                          const std::vector<std::string>& right)
{
  out << YAML::Flow;
  out << YAML::BeginSeq;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < right.size(); i++) {
    if (i != 0 && i % 4 == 0) {
      out << YAML::Newline;
    }
    out << right[i];
  }
  out << YAML::EndSeq;
  return out;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  YAML::Emitter out;
  out << YAML::BeginSeq;
  out << YAML::BeginMap;
  out << "data";
  std::vector<std::string> data(10, "blah");
  out << data;
  out << YAML::EndMap;
  out << YAML::EndSeq;
  std::cout << out.c_str() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```